# ErrorHandling Middleware catch is never caught

Tags: c#, error-handling, middleware

I have this **ErrorHandlingMiddleware** that looks like this:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context /* other dependencies */)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception ex)
    {
        var statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        if (ex is NotFoundError) statusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
        //else if (ex is MyUnauthorizedException) code = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        //else if (ex is MyException) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        var error = new AttemptError(statusCode, ex.Message, ex);

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = statusCode;

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(error.ToString());
    }
}
```

And I have added this to my **Startup** class:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
    app.SeedIdentityServerDatabase();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();

    app.UseIdentityServer();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "r3plica Identity Server v1");
        c.OAuthClientId("swagger");
        c.OAuthAppName("Swagger Api UI");
    });
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

I would expect that if I was anywhere in my application and I throw an exception, it would be caught and it would execute this line:

```
await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
```

So, I set up a test:

```
throw new Exception();
```

Which is thrown in my controller. When I run my application and then call the endpoint that has that exception thrown, it does indeed get to the `Invoke` method of my `ErrorHandlingMiddleware`, but instead of an exception being caught, it just goes to the `await _next(context)`....

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I am not sure if the registration of the error handler is correct. I registered my middlerware like this app.UseMiddleware(typeof(ErrorHandlingMiddleware));. Maybe your registration is correct as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a filter:

```
public class HttpResponseExceptionFilter : IActionFilter, IOrderedFilter
{
    public int Order { get; set; } = int.MaxValue - 10;

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) { }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception == null) return;

        var attempt = Attempt<string>.Fail(context.Exception);

        if (context.Exception is AttemptException exception)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(attempt)
            {
                StatusCode = exception.StatusCode,
            };
        }
        else
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(attempt)
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
            };
        }

        context.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

And registering it like this:

```
services.AddControllers(options => options.Filters.Add(new HttpResponseExceptionFilter()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your middleware will work if you place the call to use it after `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` in **Startup**.

[Handle errors in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-3.1) says

> Place the call to UseDeveloperExceptionPage before any middleware that you want to catch exceptions.